# Magento 1 payment captured, but order not in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Every couple of weeks we have a customer who's card was charged, but the order did not go through, it's stuck in the customers cart and it doesn't show them in abandon cart, but in the customers profile it shows the items. Logs show no issues, which is quite frustrating. Has anyone else had this issue and is there a way to get the order out of the cart in the meantime? I'd like to process it without canceling through the processor and having the customer checkout again.

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Tried that, still nothing.